# How to display Wordpress advanced custom field inside post category loop?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How do I replace the standard post category link for an advanced custom field?

I am displaying the relevant categories inside each post with the below code

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <p>
     <strong>Found in:</strong>
     <?php 
     $id = get_the_ID();
     $cats = get_the_category($id);

     $c = 0; $n = 0;
     $c = count($cats);
     foreach ( $cats as $cat ):
       $n++; ?>
       <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">
         <?php echo $cat->name; echo ( $n > 0 && $n < $c ? ', ' : ''); ?>
       </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to replace the default category url shown in the href with my custom category field called custom url for each category inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to do this.

This option is the default "WP Way" using `get_post_meta()`, more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <p>
     <strong>Found in:</strong>
     <?php 
     $id = get_the_ID();
     $cats = get_the_category($id);

     $c = 0; $n = 0;
     $c = count($cats);
     foreach ( $cats as $cat ):
        $my_custom_url = get_post_meta($cat->cat_ID, 'custom_url', true);
       $n++; ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $my_custom_url; ?>">
         <?php echo $cat->name; echo ( $n > 0 && $n < $c ? ', ' : ''); ?>
       </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If using Advanced Custom Fields you can use `get_field()`: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
   <p>
     <strong>Found in:</strong>
     <?php 
     $id = get_the_ID();
     $cats = get_the_category($id);

     $c = 0; $n = 0;
     $c = count($cats);
     foreach ( $cats as $cat ):
        $my_custom_url = get_field('custom_url', $cat->cat_ID);
       $n++; ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $my_custom_url; ?>">
         <?php echo $cat->name; echo ( $n > 0 && $n < $c ? ', ' : ''); ?>
       </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: That makes sense to me, but for some reason neither are working. The href just appears blank like there is nothing in them. The custom_url field has been populated in the admin for all categories but won't pull through to the front end.